# iPhone Video API. Is frame by frame control possible

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, video

I would like to do the following on iPhone/iPodTouch: Open a video and - via swipe or tilt - use gesture to move through each frame. Think of it as a gestural flipbook.

Does the video API support seeking frame by frame in this manner?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS4 you can do that using AVFoundation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008072

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct support for this in the SDK with Apple's move player, but you could potentially build it yourself using FFmpeg or a similar library.

Comment: How would that work with ffmpeg?  Please outline a bit more.  It doesn't make sense to me because ffmpeg itself does not run on the iPhone--it merely encodes source media to a target format that the iPhone can read.

Comment: You can compile parts of the FFmpeg library into your app; see for example http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2009-October/076618.html.  It's not exactly easy, and there are licensing issues to be aware of, but it's definitely possible.